# How can I convert a Binary search tree to a List

Tags: graph, tree, binary-search-tree

So, I programmed myself a binarysearchtree, and it is basically completly done. Delete, search, add, print: All implemented. What I want to do now though, is add a function, which removes duplicates. I have not stated what language I am doing this in, since I am not looking for a code solution, but rather a nudge in the right direction.

I have a function which prints the tree recursively like this:

```
private void PrintTree(BinarySearchTreeElement<T> currentNode)
{
    if (currentNode == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    this.PrintTree(currentNode.leftChild);
    Console.Write(currentNode.ElementValue + ", ");
    this.PrintTree(currentNode.rightChild);
}
```

It works pretty well, going through it pretty fast. I was wondering if I can use this approach, but my problem was that I do not know how to implement a list into this. The recursivenes is confusing me a little bit, so I do not know if just adding a list to the parameters will work, but I don't think it will. (If this is the completly wrong approach to removing duplicates do tell me please, but I also still want this function.)

I have tried changing this, but with a list as a return parameter it gave me a 'not all paths return a value' which is confusing me even further and making me think I am on a completely wrong approach

Comment: Do you want to get a list of all elements, remove duplicates, or get a list of elements without duplicates?

Comment: I just want a list of elements. The duplivates is something I already know how to solve once I have the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to continue doing it recursively it could look like this:

```java
private void CreateList(BinarySearchTreeElement<T> currentNode, List<T> list)
{
    if (currentNode == null) return;
    this.CreateList(currentNode.leftChild, list);
    list.Add(currentNode.ElementValue);
    this.CreateList(currentNode.rightChild, list);
}
```

or this

```java
private List<T> CreateList(BinarySearchTreeElement<T> currentNode)
{
    if (currentNode == null) List<T>();
    return this.CreateList(currentNode.leftChild).addAll(this.CreateList(currentNode.rightChild));
}
```

If your binary tree is balanced, you could consider storing the [tree in an array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation) instead of your current implementation with references to left and right children.

Comment: Thank you very much! My tree is not balanced, but I am gonna make a red black tree next

Comment: In line 4 and 6 you only call the method with only 1 parameter, and in the 2nd code it sais 'non invokable member list<t> can not be used as a method' and Operator '+' cannot be applied for list<t> and list<t>

Comment: Yes, I did not try running it because you said you where not looking for a code solution and I am not used to Java. Hope it works now.